# In leviter. How to translate?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin, christianity, bible

How do I translate "in leviter" in this sentence?

> Sensus esse videtur: ne id tantum agite ut alienorum morum censores sitis, ut facta aliorum rigide ad legem divinam exigatis & notetis, adeoque **in leviter** delinquentes tanquam atrocium criminum reos severe animadvertatis.

Here's what I have:

> The sense seems to be: do not act merely that you may be critics/censors of other's behavior, may rigidly examine and record the doings of others according to the divine law, and thus severely criticize **light** offenders as guilty of atrocious crimes.

"In" as a preposition ought to take an ablative or accusative, but I don't see what object it takes. "In leviter" literally seems to mean, "in lightly," and so I translated it just "light." How does this translation work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *in* doesn't go with the *leviter*.
It is *in delinquentes animadvertatis*, and *leviter* just adds detail into *delinquentes*.
The verb [*animadvertere* (especially II.C)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=animadverto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) can take *in* with accusative in judicial uses in classical Latin, and therefore one might expect the same in medieval Latin.